docker build keeps using long outdated file contents
I'm creating a docker out of this docker file with

docker build --no-cache -f examples/cpp/xds/Dockerfile.client -t
grpc/xds-example-cpp-client-with-td-init .

and pushed it to docker hub with

docker push grpc/xds-example-cpp-client-with-td-init:latest

In the docker ENTRY POINT I'm running this script packaged into the docker
This script pulls a gz archive with

curl -L
https://storage.googleapis.com/td-grpc-bootstrap/td-grpc-bootstrap-0.18.1.tar.gz
| tar -xz

I created a Cloud run service using the docker image I pushed:

gcloud alpha run deploy cloudrun-client --region=us-central1
--image=grpc/xds-example-cpp-client-with-td-init:latest --args=--xds_creds=true,--target=xds:///helloworld --network=default --subnet=default --mesh=$MESH

The cloud run logs have

"/init_td_and_run.sh: line 4: gcloud: command not found"
"/init_td_and_run.sh: line 5:
./td-grpc-bootstrap-0.18.0/td-grpc-bootstrap: No such file or
directory",

Neither of these usages (the error says 0.18.0 while it should be using 0.18.1, and the gcloud command usage) are present in my init_td_and_run.sh. Both these usages were present before that I have changed now but it is somehow still keeps packaging the docker with non-existant file contents. Note I have used --no-cache with docker build.
Clearly somehow the workdir retains the contents from a much earlier time. My Dockerfile.client has

RUN cp -rL /workdir/examples/cpp/xds/init_td_and_run.sh /artifacts/
COPY --from=0 /artifacts ./

which is clearly being ignored. If it is of any use, here is the full sequence of commands I used and their output starting from docker build to gcloud deploy cloud run. Can someone please help?

It looks like you forked this from the original grpc project. Your docker push is trying to push to their namespace. Are you an authorised maintainer there? Does the docker push work successfully?

Yes, I'm an authorized maintainer on grpc namespace and the push succeeded too.

You need to pull the updated image on the server before running it. There's already a grpc/xds-example-cpp-client-with-td-init:latest image on the server, so it runs that without checking if a newer version is available on Docker Hub.

I'm using gcloud run command start the service using the container. Are you saying the Google Cloud run command has an issue?

Indeed that seems to be the case. I retried the gcloud run deploy command using the digest and this time it used the correct contents.
